# style disappear when i add slash / after route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 8

when I create a route for admin

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('layouts.adminlayout');
    });
});
```

and try to display the admin page
if I Type this route : `http://localhost:8000/admin` without slash after admin I see the page work perfectly

[image]

but when I add slash after admin : `http://localhost:8000/admin/` The page appears without style

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find the solution

use : `<link href="{{asset('style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

instead of :  `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

thank you @Quentin

Answer (score 3):

You have used a **relative path** in your link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/something.css">
```

Relative paths are computed by:

1. taking the base URL of the document (usually the URL of the document)
2. removing everything after the last `/` in the path
3. appending the relative path

So your two URLs give the following results:

`/admin`:

1. http://localhost:8000/admin
2. http://localhost:8000/
3. http://localhost:8000/css/something.css

`/admin/`:

1. http://localhost:8000/admin/
2. http://localhost:8000/admin/
3. http://localhost:8000/admin/css/something.css

`http://localhost:8000/css/something.css` and `http://localhost:8000/admin/css/something.css` are **different** URLs and one of them is going to throw a `404 Not Found` error response.

---

Use an **absolute path** instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/something.css">
```

Absolute paths are computed by:

1. taking the base URL of the document
2. removing everything after the hostname and (optional) port number
3. appending the absolute path

… so you'd get the same result for each of your base URLs.

Comment: I'm using the blade template for laravel that's mean admin is not a folder is just a rout and when i inspectate my code i found all path is right

Comment: @AyoubELKhaddari If you check in your browser dev tools, in the network panel, where (which URL) does your browser look for your css stylesheet ?